# how to tell browser screen size in python

Tags: python, browser, size

I am using WebApp2 with python (and app-engine). Is there a way to tell the screen size of the browser in python? I am trying to figure if the browser size is less than 768.

Comment: while that might be possible with some extreme hackery using asm.js, I would not recommend doing that for the next 5 years. Why are you not using JS for that purpose?

Comment: @Rafael Why asm.js? How would you do it with asm.js?

Comment: @Nebril I'm telling you that with current tech, what you're trying to achieve is nearly impossible. Use javascript to get the information from the browser and send it back to the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do, but I have pretty good reasons to believe that this is something you want to handle in your css/js side of the application.

I am not familiar with app-engine, but the browser does not send it's viewport size with requests (unless you put it yourself in request data).

So if you are using ajax request - put the data about viewport in the data send to backend. If not - use css or js to handle your frontend.